# How to change MS CRM dynamic worksheet connection string

Tags: excel, dynamics-crm, crm

We are migrating our MS CRM 2016 deployment to new server with new domain name. Our customers use Dynamic worksheet for some entity views. Since we are moving to a new environment, we need to change the worksheet's crm connection string to new url.

We are unable to modify it directly under `Data->connections`. Connection string textbox is greyed out and edit query option is throwing error. Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd need to do anything at all. Once the new environment is set up, simply ask the business user's to go those entity view and generate dynamic worksheet.

In case if they use a shared path for accessing the same worksheet, just navigate to the required entity views and generate the dynamic worksheet by clicking on the Export to Excel button on list view ribbon.

Please note - 
You can email a dynamic Excel file or store it as a shared file if the recipients are in the same domain as you. When recipients open the dynamic file, they’ll see data they have permission to view in Dynamics 365 organization, so the data they see may be different from what you see.